# Многомерная база данных

Tags: база-данных, oracle, olap

Здравствуйте. Не могу понять, с чего подступиться к учебному заданию. Есть задание:

> Создать систему анализа данных с
>   помощью `Oracle Express`, состоящей из
>   многомерной базы данных, процедур
>   загрузки и  приложения пользователя.
>
> Для измерений определить перечень
>   иерархий и уровней детализации. Для
>   показателей - перечень измерений, по
>   которым он индексируется,  а также
>   разделение измерений на плотные и
>   разреженные.
>
> Многомерная база данных должна
>   содержать 2-3 показателя,
>   индексированных по 4-6 измерениям
>   каждый. На основании МБД создать
>   пользовательское приложение, 
>   состоящее из 4-5 отчетов различного
>   вида.

Я так понял, что нужно делать так:

1. Установить `Oracle Express` (вот [это](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/express-edition/downloads/index.html)?)
2. Придумать структуру (OLAP-куб). Например, такую ([звезда](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%8B)):
   [image]
3. Создать обычную реляционную базу

   ```
   CREATE TABLE ...
   ALTER TABLE ...
   CREATE SEQUENCE ...
   ```

   И заполнить с помощью, допустим

   ```
   INSERT INTO
   ```

   Будет обычная реляционная база.
4. Потом создать приложение, например, на Java + JDBC (единственное, с чем имел дело). Приложение будет показывать сводные таблицы по нескольким показателям.

Правильно ли я понимаю задание? Или этот куб надо создавать как-то по-другому?
Еще непонятна следующая часть задания:

> Многомерная база данных должна
>   содержать 2-3 показателя,
>   индексированных по 4-6 измерениям
>   каждый.

В картинке-примере у нас 4 измерения, так? А что там является показателем?
И последнее: что такое "процедура загрузки"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ответ нашелся, если кому интересно (а в след.году оно точно снова будет интересно некоторым студентам).

Оказалось, задание следует выполнять так: первые три пункта из вопроса верны. А четвертым пунктом нужно создать многомерную базу данных (МБД) на основе реляционной (РБД). Для этого нужно найти на ["складе" оркала](https://edelivery.oracle.com/), - Oracle® Express Release 6.3.4.0 Media Pack (скачивать и клиентскую, и серверную части).

Тут важно знать, что Oracle Express стабильно работает ТОЛЬКО на WindowsXP, 32 бит. Даже при работе на 32-битной Windows Vista при попытке подключения Oracle Express Administrator к Personal Express 3.2.x падает исключение, указывающее на XPHEAP.dll. По-видемому, эта "куча" не имеет обратной совместимости. В общем, приложение предлагает либо закрыть его, либо отлаживать, и закрывается!

Мой пример.

OLAP-куб с четырьмя измерениями в форме "звезда". Тема "Авиакомпания". За факт принимаются рейсы авиакомпании. 4 измерения: аэропорт вылета, аэропорт назначения, является ли рейс чартера и дата (летное время, год). Два показателя: количество рейсов и количество проданныx билетов.

Структура куба в приложении Oracle Express Administrator:
[image]

Заполнение куба лучше всего делать с помощью специальной программы на языке Oracle Express Language, потому что через пользовательский интерфейс это не представляется возможным. Подключаться:

```
sql.dbms='oracle'
sqlmessages = yes
sql connect 'system/123@xe' - это логин и пароль к РБД
```

Остальные команды описаны [здесь](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Express). После этого у вас должен получиться отчет. Стандартная диаграмма в отчете выглядит примерно так:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Обрати внимание на циферки 1, 2, 3](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/sql/69019/)

Comment: Вообще нужен Oracle, но и на том спасибо.