# Oracle Express или Oracle Database 11g OLAP Option

Tags: oracle, база-данных, olap

Что проще для выполнения учебного задания: `Oracle Express Server` или `Oracle Database 11g OLAP Option`? Знаю, что первое - это старье. Но мне только для выполнения задания. Что же лучше (и проще)?
Задание [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/65236/%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше использовать Oracle Database XE.
Весит меньше, удалить проще, оперативной памяти использует 1 гб, используется 1 процессор, бесплатная, есть графический интерфейс наподобие PMA. К тому же она совсем не стара. Последняя версия насколько помнится 11.2.

Comment: А там доступна OLAP опция?

Comment: Нет, она доступна только в Ентерпрайз версии полной Базы

Comment: Тогда она для лабы не подxодит.

Comment: В таком случае только Oracle Database. Другого выхода нет

Answer (score 0):

1-й не старье - у него просто ограничение в размере БД 4 гига и что-то еще. Для домашки вполне потянет. Я вполне серьезные задачки тягал под ним - нормально.

Comment: Выяснилось, что задание нужно делать именно в Oracle Express. Но там присутствует ряд проблем, о которых я написал ответом в теме [Многомерная база данных](http://hashcode.ru/questions/65236/%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85).